# Spring data JPA pagination happens at db level or at application level

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring Data JPA supports pagination, but how does it work?

1. Does JPA repository fetches all the data from database and deliver the chunks from application? (or)
2. Does take chunks of data from database and deliver the data to client?

Comment: It's most likely the second variant. It translates the pagination related data to SQL query (limit, offset, etc) and only selects the rows that it should, given the pagination context. You can actually see that for yourself if you use a profiler on your database and examine the queries that it generates.

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 3):

It takes chunks of data from database.
It does not fetch all of the data from database.

Generated query is using limit and offset with select query to fetch chunk of the data.

Comment: does the query use orderBy too?

Comment: If you specify it, yes. Everything you write in code using JPA is translated to query. I would suggest always specifying orderBy when working with pagination as order is not guaranteed if you do not specify it, which can lead to getting unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of pagination is precisely to select exactly the page you want to retrieve.
This avoids retrieving all the data in the DB, which can be a lot and can cause a performance problem for the application.

In fact, by passing the `Pageable` object to the method of a Spring Data Jpa repository, the pagination is applied on top of the query using the functionality of the database being used (such as `limit` and `offset`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does order by needed while working with pagination. Without ordering doesn't the query return the random data?

Comment: Yyou can create the `Pagable` object in this way: `Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"));`